# What are the preferred steps to avoid Dependency Hell in Java?

Tags: java, dependencies, dependency-management

Recently I was in a pretty much trouble with a [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) problem in Java.
Are there any proper set of procedures to avoid it in future?

Comment: Can you give us more specifics about what was your particular issue? Solving dependencies in most generic case is hard problem (and in my experience, things like OSGI just make it 10x more complicated), but there are some tricks to stay sane with medium sizes projects. Knowing particular situation can help to guide you (you have different situation when dealing with dependencies in open platform like eclipse+plugins compared to system fully developed in-house, which just has conflicting recursive dependencies)

Comment: the link that you provided shows 8 ways to solve this hell, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually I am asking how to avoid, not to solve after it happens (which is harder).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes it has some info. But I wonder if some one could give more expressive answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, use dependency manager like maven or gradle. No `lib` folder that contains third party jars, obviously no copying classes or *.java files from other project to yours. Sorry if this is obvious but I saw a lot of projects built using such technique.

The next phase however is optimization of dependencies. You can use library A and B that both use library C. It is fine if both use library C of the same version. The hell starts if they depend on different versions of library C. In most cases this does not cause any problem and you can be even not aware on this fact. However sometimes it may cause problems. To avoid this I'd recommend you from time to time check the dependency tree of your project, find duplicates and if they exist use exclude instruction of your dependency manager to exclude older version.

This however can fail because, of incompatibility of these versions of the library. In this case there is no general way to solve the problem. Sometimes you have to downgrade one (or several) of your dependencies in order to make them to work together and wait for the newer version that uses newer version of library C (in our example).

The luck of java programmers in 2016 is that most of tools are typically open source and a lot of them are available for contributions (e.g. via github), so sometimes you can contribute your fix and help yourself and to  other developers to get newer version faster.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a dependency hell in the JVM world:

1. Do not include unnecessary dependencies. Find out if there is anything for your build tool to show unused dependencies and remove them.
2. Explicitly declare all transitive dependencies necessary for compilation in your build and lock their versions to avoid surprises in the future.
3. Have a discipline marking dependencies' scope in the build: `compile | runtime | provided | test`.

In the end you will end up with a list of *all* dependencies for your project and their versions. No surprises, you get what you see and will have a control over environment.

It will be much-much easier if you would find plugins/tools for your build tool of choice.

To enforce the discipline, add the next rules to the CI:

1. Fail a CI pipeline if there are unused dependencies.
2. Fail a CI pipeline if there are undeclared transitive dependencies.

For example, a quick searching gave me:

SBT: https://github.com/cb372/sbt-explicit-dependencies

Gradle: https://github.com/autonomousapps/dependency-analysis-android-gradle-plugin